# Is there two lambda terms which are extensional equal but have different normal forms?

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

Considering untyped lambda calculus.
"normal form" simply means "beta-eta-nf".
"different/same" lambda terms is compared mod alpha-conversion.

This question is just the same as "Is there a counterexample of the following proposition?"

```
∀ t1 : term, ∀ t2 : term, (∃ t1'= nf t1  ∧  ∃ t2' = nf t2) →  (t1' = t2' ↔  ex_eq  t1  t2)
```

Or, is there a proof of it?

Comment: Are `t1, t2` assumed to be closed?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin you mean free variables? yes, I'm assuming they both contain no free variables.

Comment: To take the proposition exactly as stated, just take `t1 = t2` with no normal form :)

Comment: I don't understand what all those existential quantifiers are good for. I think the question should be rather something like *"Let `t1` and `t2` be two closed lambda terms in beta-eta normal form that are extensionally equal. Are they equivalent up to alpha-conversion?"*

Comment: Plotkin's paper "The λ-Calculus is ω-Incomplete" shows how to construct two extensionally equal but not beta-eta-convertible terms, but doesn't say whether they have beta-eta-normal forms.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov  I think I make a mistake when giving the prop,  the exists condition is a premise, not conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(In the following, read `=` as `\equiv_{\beta\eta}`)*

---

I think what you want is a direct application of the Böhm's Theorem. The theorem states:

> **Theorem (Böhm, 1968)** Let `f`, `g` be two closed lambda terms in beta-eta normal form which are not equivalent up to alpha-conversion. Then there exist closed terms `a_1`, ..., `a_n`  in beta-eta normal form such that for all `x, y` it holds:
>
> ```
>   f a_1 ... a_n x y = x
>   g a_1 ... a_n x y = y
> ```

---

A direct corollary is:

**Corollary:** If `f` and `g` are two closed terms in beta-eta normal form which are not equal up to alpha-conversion, then they are not extensionally equivalent.

**Proof:** For the sake of contradiction, assume that `f` `g` are in NF and different, but that they *are* extensionally equivalent. Choose `a_1, ..., a_n` as in Böhm's theorem. Since `f`, `g` are assumed to be extensionally equivalent, then `f a_1` must be equal to `g a_1`. But this contradicts `f a_1 ... a_n x y = x != y = g a_1 ... a_n x y` for arbitrary unequal `x` and `y`. Therefore the assumption must be false, and `f` and `g` cannot be extensionally equivalent after all.

---

Now:

**Corollary:** Suppose `f`, `g` are two closed lambda terms with existing normal forms `nf` and `ng` respectively. It holds: `nf` is equivalent to `ng` up to alpha conversion if and only if `f` and `g` are extensionally equivalent.

**Proof:** One direction: if `nf` is equivalent to `ng` up to alpha conversion, then `f` and `g` are extensionally equivalent because of confluence (Church-Rosser theorem). Opposite direction: by contraposition of the previous corollary, if `nf` and `ng` are extensionally equivalent, then they must be equal up to alpha conversion.

---

So, the answer to your question is "No, there are no two terms that are extensionally equal but have different normal forms". That doesn't help you much though, because existence of normal forms is undecidable. So, for example, it does not all of a sudden make the equivalence of two arbitrary programs decidable.

Comment: Thx,  I think this theorem is exactly what I'm looking for,  and could you please give a brief description about it's proof?

Comment: And I fixed the proposition on the question description above, will it be better now?

Comment: And I can't find this theorem in wikipedia, is there any reference which I can read in detail ?

Comment: Barendregt is the default reference for questions about lambda calculus, unfortunately I don't have a copy available right now. [This article](http://www.di.unito.it/~dezani/papers/dgp.pdf) gives three references in the second line of the introduction.